# Automatically reorder table in excel after refreshing power pivot data

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a table which is sorted by a column "rank" which contains numbers 1-10 sorted from smallest to largest. When I refresh my PowerPivot data the rankings will change, however the order of the table does not update. Is there a way to automatically update the sorting of my table after refreshing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a column which works out the ranking position of each of the 10 items from your PowerPivot data using =RANK().

Then, use either =VLOOKUP() or =INDEX() with =MATCH() against a fixed list of numbers from 1 to 10, to look them up in your new ranking column and return the appropriate items/values.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,
The problem is not updating the ranks, the rank is set in an SQL Query. My only problem is that upon updating the data the table does not re-sort itself. If I am misinterpreting how your answer may solve that please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are doing the Ranking through SQL, I'm working on the basis that this is effectively a fixed dimension in your table.

On this basis the 'Sort by Column' functionality which is on the 'Home' tab in the PowerPivot window may help you:

[image]